# is there any notification for unlock sreen by sliding to unlock iphone?

Tags: iphone, notifications, jailbreak, unlock

I work on jailbreak iphone, I want to know when user unlock the screen of iphone,is there any notification for unlock sreen by slide to unlock iphone? Thanks >>>>

Answer (score 0):

From apple docs: use UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification. This works only if your app is running so if you want to trigger some action on a background app running in a jailbroken device this is not the right solution.

UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
Posted when the application becomes active.
An application is active when it is receiving events. An active application can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, **and gains focus when the device is unlocked.**

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
UIApplication.h

Comment: thanks,I　want to lanuch my application  when user unlock the screen.

Comment: it could be a nice idea, but what happens if another app does the same? anyway I don't work with jailbroken devices, so I cannot be of further help for you.

Comment: thanks,when my app was suspended in background ,I did received the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification when unlocking the screen,but  unlock the screen to enter the springboard when my app was killed, UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification was never fired.